# Password management with RDP sessions

Tags: windows-server-2003, rdp

As part of my job I regularly remote into several Windows 2003 servers. When I do so I save my username and password to speed up this process. However, every 90 days I am required to change my password which means that all these saved RDP sessions need to be reset.

Is there an easy way to change the password on all these "saved" sessions?

or

Is there a way to blat/remove all these saved sessions so that they need to be recreated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RDP Credentials are stored in the registry, under HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client\Servers. Deleting an entry from the Servers Key will effectively delete the stored credentials.